# Monitor hits for multiple domains on a server

Tags: cpanel, bots

I'm using cpanel. I have a server that is hosting around 40 domains(sites). I'm having problems with bots on the server. I would like to see who is hitting the server across all the domains and not have to check each domain individually. How could I do this? 
CPanel provides an Error log that's for the whole domain, but I couldn't find anything that's just for a lot of hits that aren't errors.